# Modifie child link with Spring Data Rest

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

Today a have a model and this model has some childs:

```
{
  "_embedded": {
    "emailTemplates": [
      {
        "identifier": "XPTO",
        "message": "Email whatever",
        "active": true,
        "_links": {
          "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/emailTemplates/1"
          },
          "communicationChannel": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/emailTemplates/1/communicationChannel"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/emailTemplates"
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8080/profile/emailTemplates"
    }
  }
}
```

Look that communicationChannel return with link father to childs.
I need some tip to return a link direct to child like:

```
 "communicationChannel": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/communicationChannel/1"
          }
```

How can i solve that ?

Comment: Wondering the same, I'm sure there's a higher reason for the link being a sub-url of the entity, but it makes it not possible to get a list of all emailTemplates, and a list of all communicationChannels, and then putting them together in the client (which would be 2 requests/queries), instead you need to follow each separate link (many requests/queries)

Comment: Seems a duplicate of thisone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42308899/spring-rest-data-serialize-to-one-associations-as-related-entity